# Assign a variable/tag to specific text within a PowerPoint Text Box (in PowerPoint)

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I would like to update specific text within a PowerPoint text box by assigning that specific text a variable **within** PowerPoint that I can then (1) identify in Python, and (2) replace the text based on data in an Excel model.

The ultimate goal is that in the output PowerPoint presentation, we should only see the underlying value of the variable (e.g., 32.4%), not the variable name (e.g., @pct_total_var@). And if changes need to be made, the underlying reference to the variable is kept, such that I can re-run Python to update the presentation.

Note: I have already implemented a "search and replace" type solution based on answers here, and elsewhere. However the issue with that approach is that you need to work with a template PowerPoint and an output PowerPoint, because once the variables (e.g., @pct_total_var@) have been replaced with values from an Excel model, it is no longer possible to identify the variables in the output presentation file in order to update.

**Is it possible to assign a variable/tag to text within a PowerPoint Text Box?**

Below is the current Python code that I have. **I just need to be able to define variables inside PowerPoint**. But thought this might help others searching for the same.

```
from pptx import Presentation
import pandas as pd

# Paths to model, and template deck
model = "path/to/model.xlsx"
template = "path/to/template.pptx"

# Step 1: Get data from model to replace in PowerPoint
df = pd.read_excel(model, sheet_name='UpdateReportPPT')
df = df[['variable_id', 'formatted_value']]
values_to_update = df.set_index('variable_id').T.to_dict('records')[0]


# Step 2: Open template PowerPoint presentation
prs = Presentation(template)

# Step 3.1: Get shapes within  each slide
slides = [slide for slide in prs.slides]
shapes = []
for slide in slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        shapes.append(shape)

# Step 3.2: Update variables
for shape in shapes:
    
    # THIS IS WHERE I'LL IDENTIFY THE VARIABLES STORED IN POWERPOINT & UPDATE BASED ON THE EXCEL MODEL

# Step 4: Save to output PowerPoint presentation
prs.save(template)
        
print('Done.')
```

Comment: You can assign PowerPoint Tags to presentations, slides and shapes, but not to bits of text inside a shape. I couldn't find anything about working tags in Python, but here is Microsoft's page about JavaScript Tag methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/tagging-presentations-slides-shapes PowerPoint doesn't have bookmarks or fields like Word, so that's why you find so many search and replace techniques.

Comment: Check back on Reddit where you or someone with a remarkably similar problem asked about this:  https://www.reddit.com/r/powerpoint/comments/q8s6rq/is_there_a_way_to_tagassign_a_variable_to/

Comment: Thanks Steve, that was indeed me on Reddit. I’ll give your solution a spin.

Comment: Do you need to identify whole textboxes or are you talking about having multiple "fields" within a single textbox, like `{{first-name}} {{last-name}}` or something? Each shape has a name that is pretty arbitrary and that can be changed to identify the field. It's possible you could manage something clever using `<a:fld>` elements. That would require manipulating the underlying XML yourself.